# mod_pagespeed : Exclude some directory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

How can exclude some directory for mod_pagespeed using htaccess rules....

note : **I am required to disable only some directory not all files and folders**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply set `ModPagespeed off` in an .htaccess file. This will disable all rewiting of HTML in that directory. It will not stop mod_pagespeed from rewriting images/CSS/JS in that directory.

To disable rewriting of all HTML and resources, you can add `ModPagespeedDisallow http://www.example.com/subdir/*` anywhere in your config. See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/restricting_urls) for more info. Note that this requires you to specify the entire URL, not just a relative path.

Comment: Actually you can use wildcards now like ModPagespeedDisallow "*/images/captcha/*" - from https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/restricting_urls

Comment: Just loosing my words to say thanks to @sligocki ... Just saved my day with the simple answer..

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file (in the directory you want to disable), put the following lines:

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed off
</IfModule>
```

That will disable it for that directory only and will prevent errors when there's no pagespeed module enabled on the webserver.